# XPath expression for element based on containing text

Tags: xpath, selenium

I'm running out of ideas. I have identified for my Selenium test an div based on its text ("security administrator ") contained. Unfortunately, the div contains two other divs. See the example.

```
<div class="rich-stglpanel-marker">
    <div class="rich-stglpnl-marker" id="j_id194:j_id198:2:j_id199_switch_on" style="display: none"></div>
    <div class="rich-stglpnl-marker" id="j_id194:j_id198:2:j_id199_switch_off"></div>
    security administrator 
</div>
<div class="rich-stglpanel-marker">
    <div class="rich-stglpnl-marker" id="j_id194:j_id198:2:j_id199_switch_on" style="display: none"></div>
    <div class="rich-stglpnl-marker" id="j_id194:j_id198:2:j_id199_switch_off"></div>
    technical administrator 
</div>
... and so on
```

I tried that expressions:

```
//div[text()='security administrator']
//div[text()='security administrator ']
//div[text()='security administrator&nbsp;']
//div[text()='security administrator${nbsp}'] (this is a special hack from selenium)
```

Nothing works. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which node are you trying to pull? The parent node with the "security administrator" text? What info from that node?

Comment: I need the "<div class="rich-stglpanel-marker">" to click it.

Comment: They all share that class, like you said below. I'll take that to mean you want the parent node with the text.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try with this :

```
//div[contains(.,'security administrator')]
System.out.println(driver.findElementByXPath("//div[contains(.,'security adm')]").getText())
```

gave me security administrator

Answer (score 0):

try this

//div[@class='rich-stglpanel-marker']

Comment: You really paid attention. :-) Unfortunately, there are several divs that use this class. They differ only in their text contained.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `//div[@class='rich-stglpanel-marker' and text()!='']`

**EDIT**

Finally got it!

Use this: `//div[@class='rich-stglpanel-marker' and normalize-space(div[last()]/following-sibling::text())='security administrator']`

I believe that in this situation, the text "security administrator" is counted as a node, and not as the sole text value of the first div node, which is why `//div/text()` will give you multiple return lines followed by the text you're searching for, and also why you cannot apply something like `normalize-space()`,`translate()`, or even `contains()` to `div/text()` and receive results. But, since the text node doesn't have a name, that makes it a funky XPath to figure out, so navigating to the closest possible sibling node was the only option I could think of.

Comment: I advanced my xhtml code in the first post. Your idea wont work. :-( ps. The technical admin block could be sometimes before the security admin. So [0] wont work, too.

Comment: When you post a question, please be as detailed as possible the first time so we can avoid this :-)